# How to handle missing image in react 17?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting users data from an api which the profile pictures path could be invalid, so i was able to cover the part of using a default image, but the 404 error of the missing picture is still exists ... i wonder how can i prevent it. I went over ALL the solutions and still couldn't find a good one.

Here is my component that renders the image

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

  const Image = props => {

  const { image } = props;

  const [imageLoading, setImageLoading] = useState(true);

    const imageLoading_Error = () => {
      setImageLoading(false)
    }

  return (
    <div item>

        <img src={imageLoading
            ?
            `https://myusers.com/user/${image}` // don't mind the address
            :
            `${window.location.origin}/assets/default.png`}
            onError={() => imageLoading_Error()}
        />

     </div>
   )
 }

export default Image;
```

Comment: you mean the 404 status code that comes from the api?

Comment: Yes, can it be done or it's something that needs server side handling?

Comment: yes this coming from api so it should be handled in the backend, not frontend

Comment: [my](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-img-fallbacks) or similar library.

Comment: @Robert thanks - i've already tried - it's not handle 404 errors that comes from the API ...

Comment: [i tested sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-almeida-mwmic?file=/src/App.js) and in my opinion works. But i threats all errors in the same way. So you can get response status from error object. But it is enough to make fallback image.